# Can't get dropbox to move to Root on OSX?

Tags: macos, dropbox

I want to move my dropbox folder from `HDD/users/pete2k/dropbox` to `HDD/dropbox` however whenever I try and do this using the 'gear icon' --> 'Dropbox location' I get an error saying...

> Can't create a Dropbox folder in the requested location

I believe this is because of permissions. Because when I manually create the folder I have to enter my password.

Is there any way in OSX to essentially run dropbox 'as admin' like you can with windows to stop this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Go into Dropbox preferences -> Account tab. If you hold down the command/option key, the "Unlink this computer" will become "Fix permissions." Click this button (while holing down the key) to run Dropbox's permissions fix utility. You should now be able to change the location of the entire folder.

This solution worked for me about a year ago so your results may vary.

[image]

Comment: I also had to set permissions on the folder initially to allow 'everyone' (dropbox) to read and write. Then I could move it. Now I can move the permissions back as they were! :-)

Comment: I was unaware of this. +1

Comment: Just tried this; no longer seems to be possible in 3.8.6.

Comment: @Zach Are you getting the same error message as the OP? Does the "Unlink" button change at all when you hold the option key? I no longer have a Mac so I've no way of checking for a workaround.

Comment: The button says "Unlink", regardless of what modifier key is held.

Comment: What version of Dropbox?

Comment: Latest: v3.8.9.