# Mac OSX Can't Set Dropbox Folder to Root Directory

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox

I want to have my dropbox folder be at the root directory level and I have had no success finding out why it won't. I tried to fix permissions ([Can't get dropbox to move to Root on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/739741/cant-get-dropbox-to-move-to-root-on-osx)) and that completed but did not change anything. I can create it from finder but then dropbox complains it is already there. Not sure what else I can do

I am running High Sierra (10.13.2).

Comment: Always include your macOS version in macOS questions. In this case the answer is most likely different for El Capitan (10.11.x) and later, than for Yosemite (10.10.x) and earlier, due to the advent of System Integrity Protection.

Comment: Sorry.  I am running High Sierra (10.13.2).

Comment: Sounds like [SIP](https://support.apple.com/HT204899) is stopping you.